# Is there any side effect of using distributed_group_by_no_merge=1 while querying distributed table. Will they produce the same result when =0 and =1

Tags: clickhouse

I am working on one query where query throws OOM error when distributed_group_by_no_merge =0.

What could be done so that I can make the query work.
setting the max_threads=4 is making my query work and failing when max_threads=16or8.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#distributed-group-by-no-merge

results shall the same, but memory allocation and network usage is different, `0` value require much more RAM and NET on initiator node